# Custom top left and top right corner of a tableview header

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to add round corners to top left and top right corner of a tableview header programmatically.

[image: This the app I am working on The corners I want to add my app]

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by implementing the willDisplayHeaderView function:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
            let headerView = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
            headerView.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            headerView.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
            headerView.contentView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to adding `extension`

```
extension UIView {

    func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

**Use:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "header")
        let header = cell as! HeaderView

        header.contentView.roundCorners([.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 100)

        return cell
}
```